# git reset master to much older version

Tags: git, git-reset

I'm trying to reset my Git master branch to a much older version.
I made a branch to save the master branch changes in, then did a reset.
Now I am stuck and don't now what to do. The status message tells me I can fast-forward the branch, but I would want to commit the changes to get back to the old version. Master is also already pushed to the git server. What should I do next?

```
User MINGW64 application (feature/logBusiness)
$ git checkout master
M       .classpath
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

User MINGW64 application (master)
$ git checkout -b feature/v5.3.10
M       .classpath
Switched to a new branch 'feature/v5.3.10'

User MINGW64 application (feature/v5.3.10)
$ git push -u origin feature/v5.3.10
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@gitserver/srv/git/application
* [new branch]      feature/v5.3.10 -> feature/v5.3.10
Branch feature/v5.3.10 set up to track remote branch feature/v5.3.10 from origin.

User MINGW64 application (feature/v5.3.10)
$ git checkout master
M       .classpath
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

User MINGW64 application (master)
$ git reset --hard RM2_5.3.8_alpha
HEAD is now at 2055fa8 Fixed bug when KPi has no database connection assigned

User MINGW64 application (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 54 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to `git push -f master` to overwrite the remote master with your local version?

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Any other opinions?

Comment: @larsks I get `fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository`. I would do as workaround `git push -f` but I don't know whether the push applies to current branch only.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was typing in a hurry and goofed! :)  That should just be `git push -f` or `git push -f origin master`. `git push -f`, assuming you're using git more recent than 2.0, will push the current branch to the remote tracking branch (i.e., either option should be safe).

Comment: If the remote is used by others, you probably do not want to do `git push -f`.  Instead, just make a new commit with the desired tree and write a proper commit message explaining why you are rolling back to the previous state.

Comment: Luckily, I am the only one working on it. I now did the `git push -f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the remote repository, run `git push -f` while on your local `master` branch.  This will **overwrite** the remote `master` branch, replacing it with your local version.

This is in general only something you should do on a branch of which you are the exclusive user. If other people are sharing the remote `master` branch, overwriting it like this will make it difficult for them merge any changes based on the old value of the `master` branch.